# Randomize two arrays the same way, javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript and trying to sync two arrays so that both arrays have the same index location.

```
    var array1 = ["word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"];
    var array2 = [1,2,3,4,5];

    array2.sort(function(){ return Math.random() -.5});
```

This scrambles array2 into something like [2,3,1,5,4]

Now I need array1 to get the same order: `["word2", "word3", "word1", "word 5", "word4"]`

How can I do this?

Comment: Worth reading: [Array.sort() should not be used to shuffle an array](http://sroucheray.org/blog/2009/11/array-sort-should-not-be-used-to-shuffle-an-array/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be a pretty simple way to do it:

```
//assume array1 is like in your example and 
//array2 is the result of the randomization
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    result[i] = array1[array2[i]];
}
```

Comment: The original array has indexes 0 to 4, the second has values 1 to 5, i.e. the indexes don't match the values.

Comment: @RobG well spotted. Though easily fixed by adjusting the numbers either in the original array, or when accessing the indices.

Comment: This will only work for that exact example data - where second array have sequential ascending indices. Anything else - 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 and it will fail.

Answer (score 2):

you will be better of using a different structure. i.e

```
[{k: 1, v:'word1'}, {k: 2, v:'word2'}]
```

and sorting that instead

Answer (score 0):

Use associative arrays. Then shuffle the keys (eventually as a third array) and rearrange the first two array accordingly.

EDIT: Sorry, I read this as PHP and not javascript. My mistake. Maybe use objects instead of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to link values in both arrays together. Easy way to do so is to put them in third array so `pairs[index] = [ array1[index], array2[index] ]`. Sort this pairs array just as you did and then split pairs back into your original arrays.